# Global string function

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm quite new to Obj-c and i'm trying to figure out how to use global functions.
I'm working on a small project where i talk to a PHP API and this sets a session cookie, i have found how the get the cookie data, now i want to make it a little more effective by making a NSString function that gets the latest cookie value... And i am confused...

I have created a Globals object class, "Globals.h" and "Globals.m".

How do i declare a function and then access it from another file?

What i have now, Globals.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Globals : NSObject

-(NSString*)GlobalString;

@end
```

and Globals.m:

```
#import "Globals.h"
@implementation Globals
-(NSString *)Globalstring
{
    return @"This is a global string!";
}
@end
```

I understand that i have to #import the Globals.h in the files where i want to use this, but i can't see this NSString function. Help? Good link for tips and tutorials for beginners like me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `-` before the method name makes it an instance method. You probably want a class/static method so that it can be invoked on `NSString` directly. Use a `+` instead:

```
+(NSString*)GlobalString;
```

And to use it:

```
NSString *foobar = [NSString GlobalString];
```

Also note that Objective-C methods are usually `camelCase` not `CapsCase`.

Comment: That is not a bad thing to do. Just be aware of the fact that class mehtods are kinda different when it comes to accessing properties and self. The only properties really available are static variables. Which, again, is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare an instance of Globals and then call GlobalString:

You could make GlobalString a class method `+ (NSString *)GlobalString` or declare a C function in a .c file.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a globals object that contains all global variables. If you do that have a look at the singleton pattern. By doing so you could fetch your globalString by `someString = [Globals globalString];` if you design it as a class method rather than an instance method.

Hovever you could use your application delegate as a container for values and functions of globlal charachter. You can allways access your delegate by

```
MyAppDelegate *myDelegate = (MyAppDelegate) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

and then access your global function - which is now a method of MyAppDelegate:

```
returnValue = [myDelegate myGlobalFunction:theParameter];
```